# How to dynamically add a span underneath elements on focusout event?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing my own validation code, and I ran into not knowing how to dynamically adding a span, with a message, underneath an input when its value length is 0. I know I could just go and place a span underneath every input element and give them a display of none until needed, but then that would defeat the purpose of dynamically creating the spans and could possibly take a while to depending on how its used.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

```
<style scoped>
    #userDetails {
        margin-top:60px;
    }
</style>

<div id="userDetails" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="txtFirstName">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <input id="txtFirstName" is-required class="form-control input-sm" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="txtLastName">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <input id="txtLastName" is-required class="form-control input-sm" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="txtEmail">E-mail</label>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <input id="txtEmail" is-required class="form-control input-sm" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

function ValidationCheck() {
  let isRequired = document.querySelectorAll('[is-required]');
  isRequired.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('focusout', (e) => {
      if (element.value.length == 0) {
        element.style.border = "1px solid red";
        if (element.classList.contains("clear")) {
          element.classList.remove("clear");
        }
      } else {
        element.style.border = "1px solid green";
        element.classList.add("clear");
      }
    });
    element.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
      element.style.border = "1px solid green";
    });
  });
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  ValidationCheck();
});

function ValidationCheck() {
  let isRequired = document.querySelectorAll('[is-required]');
  isRequired.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('focusout', (e) => {
      if (element.value.length == 0) {
        element.style.border = "1px solid red";
        if (element.classList.contains("clear")) {
          element.classList.remove("clear");
        }
      } else {
        element.style.border = "1px solid green";
        element.classList.add("clear");
      }
    });
    element.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
      element.style.border = "1px solid green";
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style scoped>
  #userDetails {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div id="userDetails" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 control-label" for="txtFirstName">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <input id="txtFirstName" is-required class="form-control input-sm" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 control-label" for="txtLastName">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <input id="txtLastName" is-required class="form-control input-sm" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 control-label" for="txtEmail">E-mail</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <input id="txtEmail" is-required class="form-control input-sm" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `span` tag by using: [**`Document.createElement()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Additionally, you can use [**`Node.textContent`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to set a text into the `span` tag.

Then, by using [**`Node.appendChild()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) you can add the new span tag created into the proper node element.

Basically, you'll need this piece of code:

```
span = document.createElement("span");
span.style.color = "red";
span.textContent = "Invalid!";

// Just add a span tag when is necessary.
if (!element.parentNode.children[1]) {
  element.parentNode.appendChild(span); // If "element" is your input control, with parentNode finds its parent node element.
}
```

Update:

When the validation is `OK`, you can remove the added `span` by using this piece of code:

```
if (element.parentNode.children[1]) {
  element.parentNode.children[1].remove();
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  ValidationCheck();
});

function ValidationCheck() {
  let isRequired = document.querySelectorAll('[is-required]'),
    span;
  isRequired.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('focusout', (e) => {
      if (element.value.length == 0) {
        element.style.border = "1px solid red";

        span = document.createElement("span");
        span.style.color = "red";
        span.textContent = "Invalid!";

        // Just add a span tag when is necessary.
        if (!element.parentNode.children[1]) {
          element.parentNode.appendChild(span);
        }

        if (element.classList.contains("clear")) {
          element.classList.remove("clear");
        }
      } else {
        element.style.border = "1px solid green";
        element.classList.add("clear");
        if (element.parentNode.children[1]) {
          element.parentNode.children[1].remove();
        }
      }
    });
    element.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
      element.style.border = "1px solid green";
      if (element.parentNode.children[1]) {
        element.parentNode.children[1].remove();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style scoped>
  #userDetails {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div id="userDetails" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 control-label" for="txtFirstName">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <input id="txtFirstName" is-required class="form-control input-sm" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 control-label" for="txtLastName">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <input id="txtLastName" is-required class="form-control input-sm" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 control-label" for="txtEmail">E-mail</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <input id="txtEmail" is-required class="form-control input-sm" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something that I forgot to ask in my question, because I just realized this now, once that span is shown, how do I get rid of it when the value lengths are greater that zero, in short where I color the borders green

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of adding span with some text in, please edit/  update/ change for your needs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  ValidationCheck();
});

function ValidationCheck() {
  let isRequired = document.querySelectorAll('[is-required]');
  isRequired.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('focusout', (e) => {
      if (element.value.length == 0) {
        element.style.border = "1px solid red";
        
var parentDiv = element.parentNode;
var para = document.createElement("span");
var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
para.appendChild(node);
parentDiv.appendChild(para);

        if (element.classList.contains("clear")) {
          element.classList.remove("clear");

        }
      } else {
        element.style.border = "1px solid green";
        element.classList.add("clear");
      }
    });
    element.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
      element.style.border = "1px solid green";
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style scoped>
  #userDetails {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div id="userDetails" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 control-label" for="txtFirstName">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <input id="txtFirstName" is-required class="form-control input-sm" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 control-label" for="txtLastName">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <input id="txtLastName" is-required class="form-control input-sm" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 control-label" for="txtEmail">E-mail</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <input id="txtEmail" is-required class="form-control input-sm" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code adds the `span` tag unnecessarily when the *`focusout`* event is triggered many times. The result is: `This is new.This is new.This is new.`

Comment: I didnt have time to check it in details,  as I wrote in above this is only basic sample so he can update/validate for his needs.

Answer (score 1):

#### First Approach

You can have an empty span for each one of the fields and then change the `element.html` value to the error message you want to show, and then remove the `display: none;`

#### Second Approach

You can also use `document.createElement()` method to create an element and insert it where you want to
I have created a wrapper function that might help you in this case:

```
function addErrorSpan (afterId, errorMessage) { 
    // create a new span element after the element with "afterId" id with error message "errorMessage"  
    var newSpan = document.createElement("span"); 
    var newContent = document.createTextNode(errorMessage);
    newSpan.appendChild(newContent);  

    var afterElement = document.getElementById(afterId); 
    document.afterElement.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, afterElement.nextSibling);
}
```